# Getting certain items with get

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my title is a little confusing I don't know really how to explain it.

API: http://mcping.net/api/162.223.8.210:25567

So I have this code that goes to an API, and I only want it to get the 'variables' online, and max. How would I do this?

Code:

```
$.get('http://mcping.net/api/162.223.8.210:25567', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            console.log(index + "  ;  " + item)
        });
});
```

Comment: console.log(data["max"] , data['online'])

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.get('http://mcping.net/api/162.223.8.210:25567', function(data){
    console.log(data.online);
    console.log(data.max);
});
```

If your `data` is already a Javascript object, so you can call its <del>variables</del> properties like in the snippet code.

Just in case I tested it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/js18ykj1/

Comment: thanks, I just didn't know how to call them. I was trying to do stuff like online.Value

Comment: **[JSON](http://json.org/)** is a data interchange format which serializes an **`object`** as a **`string`**
In case of the _data_ variable is not parsed to be a **JavaScript Object** you should use `data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Omg, I feel so touched with so many edits. All be for the greater good.